# Is there a term that refers to both infima and suprema? (Similar to extrema for both minima and maxima?)

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Does anyone know of a term for both infima and suprema?

I was wondering if there's something similar to extrema, which describes both minima and maxima.

I've googled and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't really a term for both of them. The only thing I can think of is that they're both "bounds" (i.e. "least upper bound" and "greatest lower bound"), but that's not really what you're going for.

Comment: Follow-up: does anyone know how "tightest bounds" might translate into latin? :)

Comment: I think "extrema" would actually work well in this case, too (although sadly I don't think it's standard).